# Problem with thread synchronizing in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, runnable, executorservice

I'm well aware that this might be considered a duplicate, however I ran through many answers considering my problem here I can't come up with a solution.

I synchronized my runnable with an object shared by multiple threads and explicitly synchronized the method I am using inside, but the outcome of the program is always 3000.

I tried locking the `Counter` class but it won't change a thing.
Could anyone explain me why none of my actions work in this particular example?

```java
    public static void zad3() {
        var counter = new Counter();

        var toRun = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized (counter) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                        counter.add(1);
                    }
                }
            }
        };

        var t1 = new Thread(toRun);
        var t2 = new Thread(toRun);
        var t3 = new Thread(toRun);

        t1.start();
        t2.start();
        t3.start();

        try {
            t1.join();
            t2.join();
            t3.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("counter = " + counter.getCount());
   }
```

```java
public class Counter {
    protected long count_ = 0;

    public synchronized void add(long value) {
        count_ += value;
    }

    public long getCount() {
        return count_;
    }
}
```

**edit:**
As suggested the problem was in the loop being constantly ran a `1000` times by each of the threads.
My solution:

```java
        var toRun = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                synchronized (counter) {
                    for (var i = counter.getCount(); i < 1000; i++) {
                        counter.add(1);
                    }
                }
            }
        };
```

Comment: What results are you expecting?

Comment: @Jeppe the outcome is always `3000`, while I'm trying to achieve `1000`.

Comment: Then you should restrict the loop to run while the `counter.getCount() < 1000`, not `i`. And this means 2 operations that must be atomic (read, then write), (if you remove the synchonize around the loop).

Comment: Why do you expect the result to be 1000 if you have 3 threads incrementing it 1000 times each?

Comment: @Jeppe yeah that makes a lot of sense. Thank you!

Comment: @JacobG. this is what my excercise looked like in the book and I'm still figuring this out, I guess I thought they can go along somehow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you have synchronized the complete for loop around the "counter" variable which means that each thread will run tthe block once. 3 X 1000 = 3000

this block will be executed once per thread

```
 for (var i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
                        counter.add(1);
 }
```

UPDATE: judging from your comments that you want interrupt on 1000 example code can be:

```
 t1.start();
 t2.start();
 t3.start();

while(counter.getValue()<1000) {
    Thread.sleep(20)
}
```

Annother suggestion:

```
public class Incremetor extends Runnable {
   Counter counter;

public Incremetor(Counter counter) {
    this.counter = counter;
}
public void run() {
   counter.increment();
}

}

ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(8); // this mean 8 threads in total to do your runnables.
for (int i=0;i<1000;++i) {
     executorService.submit(new Incrementor(counter));        
}
```

Comment: I see, but is there a way I can split the `1000` I try to get between the threads? Because this is what my excercise is about, I need to do it using the for loop.

Comment: @bart-kosmala i don't understand what you want to be honest. Explain more.

Comment: You have answered my question, I'll mark it as accepted. My fix will be in the edited question.

Comment: Try this:                 int count; synchronized (counter) { count = counter.getValue(); }
                    for (var i = 0; count < 1000; i++) {
                        synchronized (counter) { counter.add(1); }
                    }
                }

Comment: @Jayr yes, that is precisely what fixed it.

Comment: @Jayr I don't think that will work reliably. All 3 threads may read `counter.getValue();` right after each other, resulting in all 3 running ~1000 iterations.

Comment: I think you are right, somehow after the counter.add, other threads need to be 'updated'. The requirement is to distribute the calls using for loop hmm: maybe after counter.add(1); count = counter.getValue(); <-- both inside the inner synchronized block

Comment: You need a loop that runs _at most_ 1000 iterations, and break, in which you synchronize access to _both_ `counter.getValue();` and `counter.add(1);`. If you don't, then all 3 threads may read that the value is 999 and all 3 increment.

Comment: The other requirement is to distribute the calls. We cannot do a 'greedy' synchronize here

Comment: @Jayr I think I start to understand what you want. How about spawning 1000 runnables each runnable incrementing the counter. public class Incremetor implements Runnable . The counter would be shared accross the Incrementors you will make a for loop where you run 1000 incrementors.

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov I think that defeats the purpose. Starting and stopping threads has a big overhead - and the workload may be 1000 now, but consider if we attempt with 1 billion instead. Your PC would crash first, but you would also spawn N threads where they would constantly be waiting for access to the counter.

Comment: @Jeppe It does not defeat the purpose. In imaginary case such approach will not bring benefits in real case scenario this is the most common aproach to doing paralelism. Check https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html.  In your case you are just incrementing a variable In real case scenariou you would be doing something far more complex most probably.

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov Yeah, I'm referring to the task of doing increments. You need to compare the overhead of thread-management with the task you're trying to parallelize. Since the thread-overhead is larger than the workload here, spawning N threads to perform N such operations is not the solution. Using an ExecutorService is different - they typically maintain a number of threads which they reuse for executing futures. This is the very argument I'm trying to make.

Comment: @Jeppe You don't need to spawn 1000 threads see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html Usualy the runnables are allocated to a thread pool. They are queued and only  some amount of them run in parallel.

Comment: @AlexandarPetrov Can you please update your snippet then? Cause you mention no ExecutorServices. Your code doesn't compile either, but I assumed `new Incrementor(counter).start();` meant spawning a Thread since you wrote _"How about spawning 1000 runnables"_.

Comment: Thank you for all the feedback, I've read all the comments, but I can't come up with a straight forward answer. Is the Executor service the best solution to this problem? I understand how it makes no real sense to do such simple task in parallel, but I just want to take a lesson from it and know the best approach.

Comment: There is no best aproach. There are many aproaches and all depend on the case. In your case the best aproach is to not use threads at all:) Or to just pick one multithreading option and explain what problems is it solving.

Comment: On my machine, with `N = 1_000_000_000L` a sequential solution takes `0m1.181s` whereas a 8-thread solution with thread-local counters takes `0m0.208s`. It depends on the problem, it may not always be possible to work thread-locally. In general you should consider how well a solution behaves as N increases infinity.

Comment: @Jeppe The weakness in your statement is that you don't know what N is and different cases N can be different things. The fastest sorting algorithm for N numbers within range is different from, the fastest known sorting algorithm for very large numbers. N can be different things fort tasks that by first look are the same like sorting of numbers.There are so many sorting algorithms and they solve different problems with different N.

Comment: @Jeppe and by the way your test for the sequental solutions is wrong. It should not take more than couple of ms 1s can be only on a Apple 2 from the 80s. You can post another question about where it is wrong. It will be quite a good question I believe. The chance that the second result for the multithreading is wrong is also significant.

Comment: You're right, the counter was still synchronized. The threaded solution is still faster, but don't mind the numbers.

Answer (score 1):

So the problem is that you let each thread attempt 1000 increments, so you'll need something like this instead:

```
while (counter.getCount() < 1000) {
     counter.add(1);
}
```

The solution you have provided may give you the correct result, but you're actually only incrementing the counter from 1 thread. When you make a synchronized block with `synchronized(object) { }`, all threads will attempt to get the lock for this block, but only one will. That means in your solution, that the first thread which gets the lock, will do all 1000 increments. When the thread releases the lock and lets the others get it, the work is already done. A solution that actually distributes the increments amongst the 3 threads, should therefore not synchronize the entire for-loop.

If you run the while-loop I suggested, you will get a lot closer to 1000, but it may actually be more than 1000. Remember to run your program 10 times or set up a test-function which runs it 100 times and reports back. The problem, is that from the point of reading `counter.getCount()`, the value may already have changed by another thread. To reliably *always* get 1000, you could ensure exclusive rights to both reading and writing to the counter:

```
while (true) {
    synchronized (counter) {
        if (counter.getCount() < 1000) {
            counter.add(1);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice that incrementing *one*  variable like this, **is slow**. You're only doing 1000, but try with one billion. In fact, the 3-threaded version takes (on my PC) 1m17s, whereas a simple sequential loop takes ~1.2 seconds. You can solve this by splitting the workload amongst the threads and letting them work on a local counter with exclusive rights and then finally add the results.

Comment: Great point, I'll keep that in mind when working further with threads.